# Underscore map behavior

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
  a = _.map(b, set);
  console.log(a);

  function set(item) {
      var cpt = item.code;

      var options = ["code"];
      RS.getCodes(cpt).then(function(response) {
          options = options.concat(_.map(response, options));
          console.log(ndcOptions);
          return options;
      });
   }
```

In my program, I want to apply function `set` to every element in list b to produce a new list `a`. However, I think there is some asynchronous execution of `set` function, when I print `a`, it gives me a blank list, and all `console.log(ndcOptions);` are executed after `console.log(a);` is executed. I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this behavior in JS, so `a` will be assigned completely before the execution of `console.log(a);` and all the lines after it.

Comment: Yes, `RS.getCodes(cpt)` seems to return a promise. *"I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this behavior in JS"* You have to write your code in such a way that it takes the asynchronous nature of the method into account. If any step of your code is asynchronous, the whole process needs to be asynchronous.

Comment: @FelixKling I called `.then` after `RS.getCodes(cpt)` so I assume that is okay to avoid the asynchronous behavior?

Comment: You are not avoiding asynchronous behavior. All that `.then` does is providing you a way to specify *what* should happen *when* the data becomes available. So you are saying *"when the data becomes available, do `options.concat(...)`"*. That moment however will be at some point in the future, after you called  `console.log(a)` (this is actually guaranteed by JavaScript, any callback passed to `.then` will be executed in the next event loop tick).

Comment: @FelixKling Is there any way I can wait for it to be done before executing anything after? I don't want to pass `then` all the way down. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this behavior in JS, so a will be assigned completely before the execution of console.log(a); and all the lines after it.

Since you want to call an asynchronous function on a set of items, the general solution is to create a promise for each item and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them.

The changes to your existing code are minimal. All you need to do is to return the promise from `set`.

```
Promise.all(_.map(b, set)).then(function(a) {
  console.log(a);
  // Anything that needs access to `a` needs to be in or called from here
});

function set(item) {
  var cpt = item.code;

  var options = ["code"];
  return RS.getCodes(cpt).then(function(response) {
//^^^^^^ return the created promise
      options = options.concat(_.map(response, options));
      console.log(ndcOptions);
      return options;
  });
}
```